# Change in minimum reputation for review task

Tags: discussion, review

I've been regularly reviewing posts on SuperUser for the past couple of months now. When I logged into SuperUser today though, I was not given the review option as always. On visiting the URL directly, I was told that the minimum rep required was now 500 for reviewing first posts and late answers.

Why the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reputation requirement was raised to combat some of the bad reviews happening with unexperienced users taking part in the queues.

If you want the full background info, see this Meta Stack Overflow discussion: [Propose a privilege to sit in the 500 reputation mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186373/propose-a-privilege-to-sit-in-the-500-reputation-mark).